# Invalid SSL certificate when building a crate with cargo

Tags: ssl, github, rust, ssl-certificate, rust-cargo

While trying an example from the tutorial (guessing game) after defining a dependency (`rand="0.3.0"`) I got this:

```
$ cargo build --verbose
    Updating registry `https://github.com/rust-lang/crates.io-index`
Unable to update registry https://github.com/rust-lang/crates.io-index

Caused by:
  failed to fetch `https://github.com/rust-lang/crates.io-index`

Caused by:
  [16] The SSL certificate is invalid
```

Added this to cargo registry git repo, but without success:

```
[http]
    sslVerify = false
```

Where to dig?

Comment: It's weird that you get an SSL warning on github.com... Are you behind an SSL proxy which would MITM your connection?

Comment: I suspect my provider does it. The question is what to do...

Comment: @tuxdevo change provider, that is definitely unwanted behaviour from an internet provider.

Comment: To add to @rubenvb's point, if your ISP modifies your SSL certificates, then you *can't trust anything secure* on the Internet. Like online shopping, or banking. Run away quickly. You can probably name and shame them somewhere online too.

Comment: It looks like ignoring the SSL certificate [is not currently supported in Cargo](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/1180).

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem today and found that my `$HOME/.gitconfig` had this:

```
[url "git@github.com:"]
    insteadOf = https://github.com/
```

I had added this to make `go get` to work over SSH for private repos. Commenting this out fixed the error.

Answer (score 0):

As said in the comments this may be someone between you and Github modifying your communication ([MITM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack)) or a misconfiguration on your system (like missing certificates). (A problem on the side of Github is not likely.)

Do debug first try with plain git: `git clone https://github.com/rust-lang/crates.io-index.git`

To get the details on what exactly failed use `openssl s_client -debug -showcerts -connect github.com:443` and if it doesn't exit on its own (because connecting worked) press `CTRL-C` to exit. The output contains information on what certificates were presented by the remote and how it was verified or failed to verify.

If it is someone modifying your communication please publish the output of this and of a `traceroute github.com` or something equivalent so others can avoid that provider.